# r - How to classify with non-numeric data?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|   | Keywords         | Paragraph        | Date       | Decision |
|===+==================+==================+============+==========|
| 1 | a; b             | A lot. of words. | 12/15/2015 | TRUE     |
|---+------------------+------------------+------------+----------|
| 2 | c; d             | more. words. many| 01/23/2015 | FALSE    |
|---+------------------+------------------+------------+----------|
| 3 | a; d; c; foo; bar| words, words, etc| 12/13/2015 | FALSE    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But with about 1500 records.

I'm trying to find the most common characteristics of a Decision. For instance:

```
Group 1: Keywords: "a", Paragraph words: ["trouble", "abhorrent"], Date: "12/12/2015", 
         Outcome: FALSE, odds of FALSE Decision: 60%
Group 2: Keywords: "b", Paragraph words: ["good", "maximum"], Date: "02/02/2015", 
         Outcome: TRUE, odds of TRUE Decision: 30%
```

Also, it would be nice if I could plot the odds on a graph like this:

```
    |   -----
60% |   |///|
    |   |///|      -----
30% |   |///|      |\\\|
    |   |///|      |\\\|
 0% +---|---|------|---|---
       Group 1    Group 2
```

I think I'm looking for regression modeling, but all the examples seem to deal with purely numeric data. How can I accomplish this using non-numeric data?

Edit: Here's a link to the dput file on Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwrbzZiF0KGtVVZ4Tk1kdDdBZXM

Comment: @rawr Sure. Sorry, I didn't know about that. Will update soon. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @rawr So I'm trying to use dput, but it keeps printing the entire data frame even though I created a new df with `head(df)`. Also, it's very messy. Am I using it right? `dput(head(df))`

Comment: @rawr How do I attach the file to this post? I mean its too big to just paste here.

Comment: `dput(head(df))` should be 6 rows and 4 columns from your example. how much text do you have in the first two columns?..

Comment: There are many types of regression for categorical data. You can build a multinomial dependent variable based on this data and use multinomial regression or other techniques. So, at the end of the day, the answer is that you need to use exploratory data analysis to decide which "buckets" you want in your outcome variable then do a little feature engineering to create it and then you can do your categorical regression models. Having said that, there are some classification techniques other than pure regression which may work better, like a decision tree classification.

Comment: One last thing -- the more outcome buckets you have the harder it will be to get a good model, but if you're only using 2 groups like in your example then you can simply use a binary dependent regression like logit, probit, or LPM and it will be much easier to get a good fit.

Comment: @rawr It's printing the entire table. I've tried saving the head as a new df, and dputting that, dputting the head itself, saving to new file, outputting to console, even df[,1:5]. It keeps giving me the full table. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: @TravisHeeter You're sure it's a data.frame?

Comment: @Hack-R I thought it was. I just edited my post to add a link to the dput output file in Google Drive.

Comment: @Hack-R OK, I'll work on that. Thanks. And I tried df[1:5,], still, it's printing the whole thing. maybe my dput install is wonky.

Comment: I finally got your data loaded. It seems you provided a 5x6 data frame but since you didn't drop the unncessary levels / metadata it was thousands and thousands of lines long.

Comment: Take a look at the [`text2vec`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/text2vec/vignettes/text-vectorization.html) package. You also might want decision trees, as opposed to a regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the data you uploaded here's a simple example:

```
mod <- glm(Decision ~ Keywords, data = df1, family = "binomial")

predictions <- predict(mod, df1, "response")

predictions
```

> ```
>   1   2   3   4   5   6 
> 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 1.0
> ```

Here's the plot you wanted, where the groups are defined by `Keywords`:

```
res <- aggregate(predictions, by=list(df1$Keywords), mean)

barplot(res$x, names.arg = c("Group 1", "Group 2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was also able to do some separate analysis on the Digest variable with the help of this website: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/text-mining-and-word-cloud-fundamentals-in-r-5-simple-steps-you-should-know#the-five-main-steps-for-creating-a-word-cloud-using-r-software

Comment: How can I tell what keywords are in the groups?

Comment: You can that by looking at the model object (`mod` or `summary(mod)`) and you can put labels on the plot accordingly. In this case Group 1 is "financial" and Group 2 is "violations".

Comment: OK, I'm not sure what I did wrong here. I ended up with a prediction for every row.

Comment: @TravisHeeter Yes, you should always have a prediction for every row (unless you have missing data and don't properly handle it). You can aggregate the predictions afterwards like I did in this answer (`res <- aggregate(predictions, by=list(df1$Keywords), mean)`).

Comment: I ran the same thing you did, but I got a barcode-looking graph.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking at at the res df, and it looks like it's not grouped.

Comment: @TravisHeeter If you ran the same thing I did *with the same data* you must have gotten the same result, so what changed? Did you add more keywords / data? If so, naturally you will have more than 2 groups. You'll have one per keyword. You can define the groups however you like though. If you only want 2 groups in your barplot and you've added data, why not make a new group variable that = 1 for one group of interest and = 0 for all others, then use that in `aggregate` instead of `df1$Keywords`. Please also read `?aggregate` so that you understand how it works and what to expect.